# BGP redistribute connected

Tags: routing, bgp, quagga

I used the quagga package to learn BGP in my test Network. So i used the command redistribute connected that sends the Router UPDATE message as expected with all the links. However my task is to prevent it from advertising a particular subnet. I read about the access-list, match and route-map but didn't really get how to prevent the advertisement of that particular address in the UPDATE messages.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are probably defining the quagga-wide access-list, and you should define bgpd access list. They are similar, but different. If I'm right, just move your ACL from zebra.conf to bgpd.conf.

P.S. Quagga is a piece of abandonware, you should really consider switching to bird.

Comment: Bird is very nice, but it has one major deficiency -- it doesn't support double-stack protocols (e.g. multi-protocol BGP).  But it is true that Quagga is starting to smell funny.

Comment: If you're talking about ipv6, then there's a bird6 version just for that. I'm using them both. With BGP too.

Comment: I'm speaking about a single protocol that carries both IPv4 and IPv6 routes.  Such as multiprotocol-BGP, IS-IS or Babel.  This is different from having two distinct protocol instances, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6.